# Yum, How to install package in other directory?

Tags: linux

According to our systemadmins, all the package I need for my work will have to be installed in /appl.

Is it possible, using 'yum' as packagemanager, to install packages into another directory as defaulted by the package?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323532/yum-install-package-name-to-different-directory

Answer (score 0):

As for rpm, it has --relocate OLDPATH=NEWPATH and --prefix NEWPATH which will allow you to change the install path for rpms marked as relocatable which will not apply to all packages. In general, it is not considered a good idea.

Comment: As far as I can remember there were applications/packages which installed flawless when using yum but gave a lot of problems when using the rpm-package ;-(

Comment: The main problem now is how to deal with non-cooperative sysadmins :-(...